# On what factors are values same in case of cross product?

Tags: vectors

Q is $( a + b) × ( a - b ) $ :

$(a × a) + (a × - b) + (b × a) + (b × - b) $. This is what I get from expanding this Q.

Now , from what I meant by factors is that when I wrote $ a × - b$. It’s direction is downwards. Online I have seen that have also written this as - b × a whose direction is upwards.

I wanted to check if this can be possible or not but couldn’t find Something particular related to it online. What I think is that in case :

1. $| a × b$| , direction will not matter since magnitude does not have a direction in it.
2. But in case of vector $ a × b$. Direction will matter which I think is the case upwards in my Q.

Could you guide me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "cross conduct" means. Do you mean the cross product? If so, $a\times -b$ is not the same as $-b\times a$. The cross product is anti-commutative, meaning that $y\times x=-x\times y$ for all $x,y$. So $a\times -b$ is equal to $b\times a$.

Comment: Do you agree my Q has the 2nd case right ?